# Convert SQL to Linq for left join with NULL in right

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

How can I convert the below SQL statement to Linq:

```
SELECT A.Application, B.Filter
FROM Applications A left join Filters B on A.Application = B.Filter OR 
B.Filter is null
```

I have written the following but am unable to figure out how to add "OR B.Filter is NULL" to it:

```
var filteredApproved = (from f in 
(from a in Applications
join b in Filters on a.Application equals b.Filter into rss
from ss in rss.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new {
a.Application,
Filter = (b == null ? 0: b.Filter)
})
```

For example, if the Applications and Filter table are as below:

```
Application
---------
A
B

Filter
--------
A
null
```

I am wanting the following result

```
Application   Filter
---------     ------
A             A
A             null
B             null
```

The Linq query returns:

```
Application   Filter
---------     ------
A             A
B             null
```

It does not return the second row that SQL is returning. I need to add " OR B.Filter is NULL" to linq.

Comment: How are your objects defined, and what relationships do you have between them?

Comment: So you want a left outer join in LINQ (and you could have used it in SQL!) That makes this an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Comment: For example, if the Applications and Filter table are as below:

Application
---------
A
B

Filter
--------
A
null


I want the following result
Application   Filter
---------     ------
A       A
A             null
B             null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ supports only *equijoins*. The only option for other type of joins is the correlated `where` (the regular `where` with condition accessing properties of both related sequences), or in case of the `left outer join` - a correlated subquery:

```
var result =
    from a in Applications
    from b in Filters
        .Where(b => a.Application == b.Filter || b.Filter == null)
        .DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        a.Application,
        Filter = b == null ? null : b.Filter
    };
```